# Trying to draw in Qt Creator, using an object as an input

Tags: c++, qt, oop

I am just creating a simple program which displays a point where a car object is, and updates where this point is using a timer so that later it is possible for it to move.

My code is currently just displaying the point at (0, 0), and I can't work out why.

My mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "twovector.h"
#include "car.h"
#include "vehicle.h"
#include <vector>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QStandardItem>
#include <QPainter>

using namespace std;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


    fCar = new Car(TwoVector(150, 2), 4);


    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(paintEvent()));
    // connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(Drive()));
    timer->start(10);


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::Drive(){
    fCar->Drive(fCar->GetVelocity());
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *){

    QPainter painter(this);
    QPen DotPen(Qt::red);
    DotPen.setWidth(10);

    painter.setPen(DotPen);
    //painter.drawPoint(0, 0);

    painter.drawPoint((fCar->GetPosition().GetRadius())*(cos(fCar->GetPosition().GetAngle()))
                      , (fCar->GetPosition().GetRadius())*(sin(fCar->GetPosition().GetAngle())));
        //Draw the dot, where the centre of the window is (0,0)
}
```

The mainwindow header file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "car.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    void Drive();

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    Car *fCar;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

vehicle.ccp  (from which the car class inherits from)

```
#include "vehicle.h"
#include "twovector.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Vehicle::Vehicle(){
}

Vehicle::Vehicle(TwoVector position, double velocity){
    fPosition = position;
    fVelocity = velocity;
}

Vehicle::~Vehicle(){
}

void Vehicle::SetValue(string ValueName, double Value) {
    if(ValueName.compare("Radius") == 0)
        fPosition.SetRadius(Value);
    else{
        if(ValueName.compare("Angle") == 0)
            fPosition.SetAngle(Value);
        else if(ValueName.compare("Velocity") == 0)
            fVelocity = Value;
        else
            cerr << "Unknown field entered: " << ValueName << endl;
    }

}

void Vehicle::Drive(int velocity){
    fPosition.SetAngle(fPosition.GetAngle() + (velocity)/(fPosition.GetRadius()));
}
```

vehicle.h:

```
#ifndef VEHICLE_H
#define VEHICLE_H
#include "twovector.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vehicle
{
public:
    Vehicle();

    Vehicle(TwoVector position, double velocity);

    ~Vehicle();

    inline TwoVector GetPosition() {return fPosition;}

    inline double GetVelocity() {return fVelocity;}

    inline void SetPosition(TwoVector position) {fPosition = position;}

    void SetValue(string ValueName, double Value);

    void Drive(int velocity);

private:

    TwoVector fPosition;
    double fVelocity;
};

#endif // VEHICLE_H
```

Twovector.ccp:

```
#include "twovector.h"

TwoVector::TwoVector(){
    fRadius = 0;
    fTheta = 0;
}

TwoVector::TwoVector(double radius, double theta){
    fRadius = radius;
    fTheta = theta;
}

TwoVector::~TwoVector(){
}

TwoVector TwoVector::operator +=(TwoVector position1){
    TwoVector position2;
        //Creates a new object which is given a position
    position2.fRadius = sqrt(((fRadius)*(fRadius))+((position1.fRadius)*(position1.fRadius))
                             + 2*((position1.fRadius)*(fRadius))*cos((position1.fTheta)-(fTheta)));
    position2.fTheta = fTheta + atan2((position1.fRadius)*(sin((position1.fTheta)-(fTheta))),
                                 fRadius + (position1.fRadius)*(cos((position1.fTheta)-fTheta)));
    return(position2);
    //New position returned

}
```

TwoVector.h:

```
#ifndef TWOVECTOR_H
#define TWOVECTOR_H
#include <math.h>


class TwoVector {
public:
    TwoVector();

    TwoVector(double radius, double theta);

    ~TwoVector();

    inline double GetX() {return fRadius*cos(fTheta);}
    inline double GetY() {return fRadius*sin(fTheta);}
    inline double GetRadius() const {return fRadius;}
    inline double GetAngle() const {return fTheta;}
        //Accessor functions, these simply return the value of the coordinates


    inline void SetRadius(double radius) {fRadius = radius;}
    inline void SetAngle(double theta) {fTheta = theta;}
    inline void SetRadiusAndAngle(double radius, double theta) {
        fRadius = radius, fTheta = theta;}
        //Mutator function to change the position

    TwoVector operator += (TwoVector);
        //Operator overloading so that vectors can be added


private:

    double fRadius;
    double fTheta;

};

#endif // TWOVECTOR_H
```

car.h:

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H
#include "twovector.h"
#include "vehicle.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Car: public Vehicle {
public:
    Car();

    Car(TwoVector position, double velocity);

    ~Car();

private:

    TwoVector fPositioncar;
    double fVelocitycar;

};

#endif // CAR_H
```

car.cpp:

```
#include "car.h"

Car::Car(){
}

Car::Car(TwoVector position, double velocity){
    fPositioncar = position;
    fVelocitycar = velocity;
}

Car::~Car(){
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not call the paintEvent method directly, you must do it through the `update()` method and as in your case you want to update the position, it is advisable to make the following modifications:

```
[...]

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    //connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(paintEvent()));
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(Drive()));
    timer->start(10);
[...]

void MainWindow::Drive(){
    fCar->Drive(fCar->GetVelocity());
    update();
}

[...]
```

Another problem is that you have not called the parent's constructor:

**car.cpp**

```
#include "car.h"

Car::Car():Vehicle(){
}

Car::Car(TwoVector position, double velocity):Vehicle(position, velocity){
    fPositioncar = position;
    fVelocitycar = velocity;
}

Car::~Car(){
}
```

Also velocity is a value of type double, on the other hand Drive is configured for integer, you must change it to:

**vehicle.cpp**

```
[...]
void Vehicle::Drive(double velocity){
    fPosition.SetAngle(fPosition.GetAngle() + (velocity)/(fPosition.GetRadius()));
}
```

The complete project with the modifications can be seen in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/47520108).

Comment: Ah ok, so the update function will tell the program to call the paint event when it returns to the main loop? I think I get that, but the point still doesn't seem to be moving, or even starting on the position of the object?

Comment: What is Car class? You could share your entire project to help you.

Comment: The car class just has a constructor and destructor and inherits from the vehicle class - its kind of pointless at the moment but its just in order to structure it later when I add different types of object that inherit from the vehicle class. I will add it to the main question.

Comment: @JonathanParkes The simplest for me would be that you share your code via github, drive, dropbox or similar to quickly review the error.

Comment: Yes I had forgotten to call the inherited constructor... But it doesn't seem to be updating when I call the drive function?

Comment: Have you executed my project?

Comment: @JonathanParkes The trajectory of your element is circular and the center is the upper left corner and initially you can not see it but if you wait a few seconds you will see it clearly.